# The Pymongo query with $gte returned different results compared to the client-side query

Tags: python, pymongo

Here is the code by pymongo:

```py
db['all_data'].find(
        {"noCacheTime": {"$gte": 1691338596 }}
    )
```

get two results.

But when I query the same in compass:

```bash
db.getCollection("all_data").find({ "noCacheTime": { $gte: 1691338596 } }).limit(1000).skip(0)
```

get 7 results.

The data type of "noCacheTime" is Int.

The same result from pymongo and compass.

Comment: Are you using the same database?

Comment: Yes, I use the same collection.

Comment: How is `db` defined in Python and also in MongoDB Compass?

Comment: For python, it likes `client = pymongo.MongoClient(host='localhost', port=27017)
db = client['book']`. For compass, i access it by `db.getCollection("all_data")`. The structure is MongoDB -> database:book ->collection:all_data

Comment: The database fields: url, result, noCacheTime, here is a sample: {"url": "http://example.com", "result":{"msg":"ok"}, "noCacheTime": 1691350387}

Comment: I see how `db` is defined in Python, but I don't understand how you are setting it in MongoDB Compass.  Are you using the builtin `mongosh` and typing `use book` at the prompt?